# Good Julia code for a bifurcation diagram

Tags: matlab, julia

I am in the process of migrating all my Matlab code into Julia. I have an old Matlab script that produces the standard bifurcation diagram for the logistic map, quite fast: ≈0.09s for the loop, ≈0.11s for the plot to come out (Matlab 2019a). The logistic map is well known and I will be brief here: `x(t+1) = r*x(t)*(1-x(t))`, `0 ≤ r ≤ 4`. For accuracy, I choose `maxiter = 1000` and `r = LinRange(0.0,4.0, 6001)`.

I have tried to rewrite my Matlab code into Julia, but I am still a clumsy Julia programmer. The best I could come up with was to get `1.341015 seconds (44.79 M allocations: 820.892 MiB, 4.60% gc time)` for the loop to run, and Plots.jl takes `2.266 s (6503764 allocations: 283.60 MiB)` to save a pdf file of the plot (not bad), while it takes around 17s to get the plot to be seen in the Atom plots pane (that's OK with Plots). This was done with Julia 1.5.3 (both in Atom and VS Code).

I would be grateful if someone could provide some help with my Julia code below. It runs, but it looks a bit primitive and slow. I tried to change the style and looked for performance tips (@inbounds, @simd, @avx), but always got stuck in one problem or another. It simply does not make sense to have the same loop 15 times faster in Matlab than in Julia, and I know that. Actually, there is a piece of Matlab code that I particularly like (by Steve Brunton), which is extremely simple and elegant, and (apparently) easy to be re-written in Julia; but I stumbled here as well. Brunton's loops run in just ≈0.04s, and can be found below.

Help will be appreciated. Thanks. The plot is the usual one:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEKG4.png)

**My Matlab code:**

```
tic 
hold on % required for plotting all points
maxiter = 1000;
r1 = 0;
r4 = 4;
Tot = 6001;
r = linspace(r1, r4, Tot);   % Number of r values (6001 points)
np = length(r);
y = zeros(maxiter+1, Tot);   % Pre-allocation
y(1,1:np) = 0.5;            % Generic initial condition

for n = 1 : maxiter
   y(n+1,:) = r.*y(n,:) .* (1-y(n,:)); % Iterates all the r values at once
end
toc

tic
for n = maxiter-100 : maxiter+1  % eliminates transients
    plot(r,y(n,:),'b.','Markersize',0.01)
    grid on
    yticks([0 0.2 0.4 0.6 0.8 1])
end
hold off
toc
```

**My Julia code:**

```
using Plots
using BenchmarkTools
#using LoopVectorization
#using SIMD

@time begin
    rs = LinRange(0.0,4.0, 6001) 
    #rs = collect(rs)
    x1 = 0.5
    maxiter = 1000 # maximum iterations
    x = zeros(length(rs), maxiter) # for each starting condition (across rows)
    #for k = 1:length(rs)
    for k in eachindex(rs)
        x[k,1] = x1 # initial condition
        for j = 1 : maxiter-1
            x[k, j+1] = rs[k] * x[k, j] * (1 - x[k,j])
        end
    end
end

@btime begin
    plot(rs, x[:,end-50:end], #avoiding transients
    seriestype = :scatter, 
    markercolor=:blue,
    markerstrokecolor=:match,
    markersize = 1,
    markerstrokewidth = 0,
    legend = false,
    markeralpha = 0.3)
    #xticks! = 0:1:4
    xlims!(0.01,4)
end
```

**Steve Brunton's Matlab code:**

```
tic
xvals=[];

for beta = linspace(0,4,6001)
    beta;
    xold = 0.5;
    %transient
    for i = 1:500
        xnew = (beta*(xold-xold^2));
        xold = xnew;
    end
    %xnew = xold;
    xss = xnew;

    for i = 1:1000;
        xnew = ((xold-xold^2)*beta);
        xold = xnew;
        xvals(1,length(xvals)+1) = beta; % saving beta values
        xvals(2,length(xvals)) = xnew; % saving xnew values
        if (abs(xnew-xss) < .001)
            break
        end
    end
end 
toc

tic
plot (xvals(1,:),xvals(2,:),'b.', 'Linewidth', 0.1, 'Markersize', 1)
grid on
%xlim([2.5 4])
toc
```

Comment: Sorry, the **Julia code** I presented above had a typo in the inner loop. Where one finds `N-1` it should be `maxiter-1`. The piece of Julia code above has already been corrected.

Comment: Just one more point. The **execution time** in the Julia code should be measured with `@time`, not `@btime`. BenchmarkTools will break the loops and the output will be completely different from what one would expect from such a bifurcation diagram.

Comment: Can you elaborate what do you mean by "BenchmarkTools will break the loops"? Never experienced this behaviour.

Comment: Sorry, I probably did not choose the right words. I meant that if I run the execution time of my first block with `@btime`, it gives `26.226 ms (2 allocations: 45.78 MiB)` and returns `nothing`. Thus, I can not obtain the plot due to `UndefVarError: x not defined`. On the other hand, if the former block is run with `@time`, it provides the execution time, and the plot can be easily obtained straight away.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the meantime, I learned that the `@avx` macro from `LoopVectorization.jl` should not be applied to two loops that are not independent (which is the case with these two loops), and if I change the order of the loops, performance will be enhanced 5x. So, a better piece of code to produce a bifurcation diagram for the logistic map will be something like this:

```
using Plots
using BenchmarkTools
#using LoopVectorization
using SIMD

function bifur!(rs, x, xs, maxiter)
    x[:,1] .= xs
    for j in 1:maxiter-1 #the j loop needs to be sequential, so should be the outer loop
        @inbounds @simd for k in 1:length(rs) # the k loop should be the innermost since it is first on x.
            x[k, j+1] =  rs[k] * x[k, j] * (1 - x[k,j])
        end
    end
    return x
end

rs = LinRange(0.0, 4.0, 6001) #rs = collect(rs)
xs = 0.5
maxiter = 1000 # maximum iterations
x = zeros(length(rs), maxiter)

bifur!(rs, x, xs, maxiter)

@benchmark bifur!($rs, x, $xs, $maxiter) setup=(x = zeros(length($rs), $maxiter)) evals=1

@btime begin
    plot(rs, x[:, end-50:end], #avoid transients
    #plot($rs, @view($x[:, end-50:end]),
    seriestype = :scatter,
    markercolor=:blue,
    markerstrokecolor=:match,
    markersize = 1.1,
    markerstrokewidth = 0,
    legend = false,
    markeralpha = 0.3)
    #xticks! = 0:1:4
    xlims!(2.75,4)
    #savefig("logistic_bifur.pdf")
end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@time begin
    rs = LinRange(0.0,4.0, 6001) 
    x1 = 0.5
    maxiter = 1000 # maximum iterations
    x = zeros(length(rs), maxiter)
    for k in eachindex(rs)
        x[k,1] = x1 # initial condition
        for j = 1 : maxiter-1
            x[k, j+1] = rs[k] * x[k, j] * (1 - x[k,j])
        end
    end
end
```

shows:

1.490238 seconds (44.79 M allocations: 820.892 MiB, 5.81% gc time)

whereas

```
@time begin
    let
        rs = LinRange(0.0,4.0, 6001)
        x1 = 0.5
        maxiter = 1000 # maximum iterations
        x = zeros(length(rs), maxiter)
        for k in eachindex(rs)
            x[k,1] = x1 # initial condition
            for j = 1 : maxiter-1
                x[k, j+1] = rs[k] * x[k, j] * (1 - x[k,j])
            end
        end
    end
end
```

shows

0.044452 seconds (2 allocations: 45.784 MiB, 29.09% gc time)

`let` introduces a new scope, so your problem is that you're running in global scope.

The compiler finds it difficult to optimise code in global scope, because any variables can be accessed from any location in your (possibly 1000s of lines of) source code. As described in [the manual](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/), this is the number 1 reason why code can run slower than it should.

Comment: Thank's a lot for your help. There remains a problem that I don't know how to solve. If you start by running your block, **as it stands**, it runs `0.036124 seconds (2 allocations: 45.784 MiB, 19.01% gc time)`, and it returns `nothing`. If instead, we add `return x` after the outer-loop, your block will return a `6001×1000 Array{Float64,2}:`, but saves no output in the Workspace. Interestingly, Julia does not provide any information about the run-time.

Comment: My problem is that when I move to the second block (to produce the plot), I get the reply `UndefVarError: x not defined`. How can I call the x-array to create the plot with Plots? This problem will not exist if you **firstly** run my first block and next you run yours because the output of mine has already been stored in the Workspace of Atom. Thank you.

Comment: I'd suggest keeping questions focussed on a single specific issue, otherwise the Q&A format gets muddied with comments and edits. I think you should investigate using functions more. Julia prefers your code when it's organised into functions...

Answer (score 1):

I do not know, why you were flagged, maybe this way of communication is not very suitable for StackOverflow, I can recommend to use https://discourse.julialang.org which is more suitable for long discussions.

Regarding your code, there couple of things that can be improved.

```
using Plots
using BenchmarkTools
using LoopVectorization

function bifur(rs, xs, maxiter)
    x = zeros(length(rs), maxiter) # for each starting condition (across rows)
    bifur!(x, rs, xs, maxiter)
end

function bifur!(x, rs, xs, maxiter)
    # @avx - LoopVectorization is broken on julia nightly, so I had to switch to other options
    @inbounds @simd for k = 1 : length(rs) # macro to vectorize the loop
        x[k,1] = xs # initial condition
        for j = 1 : maxiter-1
            x[k, j+1] =  rs[k] * x[k, j] * (1 - x[k,j])
        end
    end

    return x
end
```

As you can see, I split `bifur` in two functions: mutating, which was denoted with exclamation mark and non mutating, which is just named `bifur`. This pattern is common in Julia and helps to properly benchmark and use code. If you want faster version which do not allocate, you use mutating version. If you want slower version with guaranteed result (i.e. it does not change between different runs) you use non mutating version.

Here you can see benchmark results

```
julia> @benchmark bifur($rs, $xs, $maxiter)
BenchmarkTools.Trial:
  memory estimate:  45.78 MiB
  allocs estimate:  2
  --------------
  minimum time:     38.556 ms (0.00% GC)
  median time:      41.440 ms (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        45.371 ms (10.08% GC)
  maximum time:     170.765 ms (77.25% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          111
  evals/sample:     1
```

This looks reasonable - best runtime is 38 ms and 2 allocations apparently coming from allocating `x`. Note also that variables `xs` and others were interpolated with `$` symbol. It helps to benchmark properly, more can be read in [BenchmarkTools.jl manual](https://github.com/JuliaCI/BenchmarkTools.jl/blob/master/doc/manual.md#interpolating-values-into-benchmark-expressions).

We can compare it with mutation version

```
julia> @benchmark bifur!(x, $rs, $xs, $maxiter) setup=(x = zeros(length($rs), $maxiter))
evals = 1
BenchmarkTools.Trial:
  memory estimate:  0 bytes
  allocs estimate:  0
  --------------
  minimum time:     25.574 ms (0.00% GC)
  median time:      27.556 ms (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        27.717 ms (0.00% GC)
  maximum time:     35.223 ms (0.00% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          98
  evals/sample:     1
```

I had to add [setup phase](https://github.com/JuliaCI/BenchmarkTools.jl/blob/master/doc/manual.md#setup-and-teardown-phases) and now you can see that there are no allocation, as it can be expected and it runs slightly faster, 13 ms difference is `x` initialization.

Here is a note: your benchmark results are wrong, since you do not reset `x` between runs (no setup phase), so `x` was properly initialized on the first run, but on all other runs no additional calculations were performed. So you get something like 100 runs with first run equals to 30 ms and all other runs equals to 4ms, so on average you get 4 ms.

Now, you can use this function straightforwardly

```
x = bifur(rs, xs, maxiter)

@btime begin
    plot($rs, @view($x[:, end-50:end]), #avoid transients
    seriestype = :scatter,
    markercolor=:blue,
    markerstrokecolor=:match,
    markersize = 1.1,
    markerstrokewidth = 0,
    legend = false,
    markeralpha = 0.3)
    #xticks! = 0:1:4
    xlims!(2.75,4)
    #savefig("zee_bifurcation.pdf")
end
```

Note that here I use interpolation again, and also `@view` for proper array slicing. Thing is, expressions like `x[:, end-50:end]` create new copy of the array, which can slow down calculations sometimes. Of course it is of little importance in the case of the `Plots.jl`, but can be useful in other calculations.

Comment: Thank's a lot for your help. I have tried to replicate your results with @avx. 
    `@benchmark bifurc($r_s, $x_s, $maxiter)`
    `mean time:        12.796 ms (13.40% GC)`

    `@benchmark bifurc!(y, $r_s, $x_s, $maxiter) setup=(y = zeros(length($r_s), $maxiter))`
    `mean time:        3.500 ms (0.00% GC)`
Well, your point forced me to take a look at the BencmarkTools docs. I think the difference between my replication and your results may be related to @avx. In the kind of loops I had, `@inbounds` and `@simd` seemed to have little impact. Thank's.

Comment: It looks your computer is just better then mine :-) Mine needs 15ms just to zero 1000x6001 matrix.

Regarding your benchmarks: it looks like you forget to include `evals = 1`, correct code should be `@benchmark bifurc!(y, $r_s, $x_s, $maxiter) setup=(y = zeros(length($r_s), $maxiter)) evals = 1` otherwise you get the same problem, `y` is reused multiple times before being reset.

And I would like to advise one more time to switch to https://discourse.julialang.org/, it is more appropriate to this kind of discussions.

Comment: With `@inbounds @simd`: `mean time:  20.072 ms (0.00% GC)`. With `@avx` `mean time:  3.377 ms (0.00% GC)`.

Answer (score 0):

I was frustrated by the Julia code's poor style and performance for the bifurcation diagram of the logistic map I presented above. I am a kind of a newbie to Julia and expected some help for a problem that is not that difficult for an experienced Julia programmer. Well, looking for help, I just got knocked on my head with flags, telling me that I was deviating from my question or something else. I was not.

I feel better now. The code below runs two loops (inside a function), filling in a `6001×1000 Array{Float64,2}` in just `3.276 ms (0 allocations: 0 bytes)`, and the plot comes out in `17.660 ms (83656 allocations: 11.32 MiB)` right on the Atom's plots pane. I think it can still be improved, but (for me) it's OK as it stands. Julia rocks.

```
using Plots
using BenchmarkTools
using LoopVectorization

function bifur(rs, x, xs, maxiter)
    @avx for k = 1 : length(rs) # macro to vectorize the loop
        x[k,1] = xs # initial condition
        for j = 1 : maxiter-1
            x[k, j+1] =  rs[k] * x[k, j] * (1 - x[k,j])
        end
    end
    #return x
end

rs = LinRange(0.0, 4.0, 6001) #rs = collect(rs)
xs = 0.5
maxiter = 1000 # maximum iterations
x = zeros(length(rs), maxiter) # for each starting condition (across rows)

@btime begin 
    bifur(rs, x, xs, maxiter) 
end

@benchmark bifur(rs, x, xs, maxiter)

@btime begin
    plot(rs, x[:, end-50:end], #avoid transients
    seriestype = :scatter,
    markercolor=:blue,
    markerstrokecolor=:match,
    markersize = 1.1,
    markerstrokewidth = 0,
    legend = false,
    markeralpha = 0.3)
    #xticks! = 0:1:4
    xlims!(2.75,4)
    #savefig("zee_bifurcation.pdf")
end
```

The plot should look like this: [image]

Does anyone have an idea of how to adapt Brunton's above Matlab code to Julia? I kind of like his style. It looks beautiful for teaching.